# Retrieve mysql table comment using DatabaseMetaData

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, vaadin, database-metadata

So I'm using Vaadin Java web framework for a project which requires the ability to edit the table. Vaadin provides a way to get `Connection` object from `SimpleJDBCConnectionPool` ([Here's the API](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/connection/SimpleJDBCConnectionPool.html))

From the `Connection` I can get `DatabaseMetaData` object. And I have the following code:

```
private List<String> getTableNames(DatabaseMetaData md) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<String> tables = new ArrayList<String>();
        ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "", null);
        while (rs.next()) {
            tables.add(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME")); //Column 3 is for table name
            Logger.getLogger(CodeContainingClass.class.getName()).
                    info("Comment: " + rs.getString("REMARKS")); //Column 5 is for remarks
        }
        return tables;
}
```

It retrieves the Table name correctly, but unfortunately the REMARKS returns `null`. ([Here's the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I verified that the table has a comment using the following query:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name='tablename';
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [MySQL Connector/J bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65213) (specifically the comment at 27 Jun 2012 11:26 and 28 Jun 2012 11:18). You need to specify connection property `useInformationSchema=true` to get this functionality.

See also the [Connector/J Connection properties](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

Comment: By adding useInformationSchema=true in the connection url, the getTables() returns empty ResultSet.

Comment: You may need to replace the value `""` for the `tableNamePattern` parameter with either `"%"` or `null`.

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL the comment associated with each table is available from the `information_schema`.

Try this query:

```
 SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COMMENT
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourDatabaseName'
```

Be sure to substitute the data base name you're actually using.