# Can't retrieve the comment for columns but not table when using SchemaCrawler

Tags: schemacrawler

I am using SchemaCrawler to get the metadata for MySQL5.7 tables using the following code:

```
final Connection connection = ...;
final DatabaseSpecificOverrideOptions databaseSpecificOverrideOptions =
                        SchemaCrawlerUtility.matchDatabaseSpecificOverrideOptions(connection);

final SchemaCrawler schemaCrawler = new SchemaCrawler(connection, databaseSpecificOverrideOptions);

final SchemaCrawlerOptions options = new SchemaCrawlerOptions();
options.setSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevelBuilder.maximum());
options.setTableInclusionRule(new IncludeAll());
options.setColumnInclusionRule(new IncludeAll());

final Catalog catalog = schemaCrawler.crawl(options);
final Collection<Table> tables = catalog.getTables();

for (Table t : tables) {
    logger.info("Table comment: {}", t.getRemarks());
}
```

This is the test table:

```
create table testtable (
    id bigint comment 'key level comment', 
    name varchar(32) comment 'column level comment'
) comment='table level comment';
```

I can get the column-level comments, but I never can get the table-level comment.

Is there anything that I mis-configured ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an annoyance with the MySQL JDBC driver. You need to set `useInformationSchema=true` in your JDBC connection URL when creating a connection. For more information, please take a look at the StackOverflow question, [Retrieve mysql table comment using DatabaseMetaData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146230/retrieve-mysql-table-comment-using-databasemetadata).

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)

Comment: So how to get the comment for the index ? Even if I have added useInformationSchema=true, the comment from the index is still null.

Comment: Please create a separate StackOverflow question for the index, with example DDL on how to create the index, and I will research for you.

Comment: A new question is created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220025/cant-retrieve-comments-for-indexes-when-using-schemacrawler-and-mysql5-7