# Can't retrieve comments for indexes when using SchemaCrawler and MySQL5.7

Tags: schemacrawler

I can retrieve comments for tables and columns by using SchemaCrawler and MySQL5.7, but it failed for the indexes' comments. This is an example:

1) Table definition

```
create table testtable(
  id bigint unsigned auto_increment,
  city_id varchar(256),
  person_id varchar(256),
  primary key(id) comment 'This is comment for the primary key',
  key idx1 (city_id, person_id) comment 'This is the comment for test index'
) comment='This is the comment for test table';
```

2) Java code

```
// jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useInformationSchema=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
final Connection connection = ...;
final DatabaseSpecificOverrideOptions databaseSpecificOverrideOptions =
                        SchemaCrawlerUtility.matchDatabaseSpecificOverrideOptions(connection);

final SchemaCrawler schemaCrawler = new SchemaCrawler(connection, databaseSpecificOverrideOptions);

final SchemaCrawlerOptions options = new SchemaCrawlerOptions();
options.setSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevelBuilder.maximum());
options.setTableInclusionRule(new IncludeAll());
options.setColumnInclusionRule(new IncludeAll());

final Catalog catalog = schemaCrawler.crawl(options);
final Collection<schemacrawler.schema.Table> tables = catalog.getTables();

for (schemacrawler.schema.Table t : tables) {
    System.out.println(t.getPrimaryKey().getRemarks());
    for (schemacrawler.schema.Index index : t.getIndexes()) {
        System.out.println(index.getRemarks());
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I should adjust ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, index comments are not supported for MySQL in SchemaCrawler 14.16.01. Please make sure that you include the [us.fatehi:schemacrawler-mysql jar file](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22us.fatehi%22%20AND%20a%3A%22schemacrawler-mysql%22) on your classpath.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Looking forward to see the new release.

Comment: Please use SchemaCrawler 14.06.01